# If $ 0 \le b \le a$, Prove $a \pmod b \lt \frac{a}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> If $ 0 \le b \le a$, Prove $a \pmod b \lt \frac{a}{2}$

Intuitively it sounds right, the remainder of the $a \pmod b$ has to be lower than $\frac{a}{2}$.

I tried to solve this like this, let's *assume* that $a \pmod b \gt \frac{a}{2}$, and look at the numbers $a = 8$ and $b = 0,1,2,...,8$ and check the remainders, we will see that the remainder will be $0,1,2,3$. which means if I go somehow with induction I'll prove that for any $a$,$b$. Is there a chance you can help me write it right with induction?

I thought about:

Base: $a = 1, b = 1$. Works

Assumption: $a = n , b = 1,2,..,n$

Prove for $a = n+1, b = 1,2,..,n+1$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here, maybe there is a simpler proof? So for my bad math skills :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $a = qb + r$, where $r$ is the remainder on dividing $a$ by $b$ ($a \mod b$), so $0 \le r < b$.

From $b \le a$, we get that $q \ge 1$.

Then we have to prove that $r < \frac{a}{2}$. Note that
$$
\frac{a}{2}
= \frac{qb + r}{2} \ge \frac{b + r}{2} > \frac{r + r}{2} = r,
$$
which proves it. Make sure you can justify each equality or inequality in the above equation.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b \le \frac{a}{2}$, then the modulo value is also $\lt \frac{a}{2}$

So we have that $a \ge b > \frac{a}{2}$. We can then subtract only exactly one time $b$ from $a$ and get a remainder $\lt \frac{a}{2}$